# Python profiler usage with objects

Tags: python, profiler

I have a specific question regarding the usage of profiler. I am new to python programming
I am trying to profile a function which I want to invoke as a class method, something like this

```
import profile

class Class:
    def doSomething():
        do here ..

    def callMethod():
        self.doSomething()
```

instead of this I want to use

```
    profile.run(self.doSomething())
```

but the `profile.run` expects the string inside it and I get error

```
TypeError: exec: arg 1 must be a string, file, or code object
```

Can somebody please help?

Thank you

Comment: so? why don't you pass a string to the `profile.run`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fixed!!!

Instead of profile, I used cProfile module that as per the python docs has much lesser overhead

Ref : http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#introduction-to-the-profilers

with cProfiler, one can actually pass the local and global params using the runctx module
so for the same problem, I did the following:

```
import cProfile
cProfile.runctx('self.doSomething()',globals(),locals())
```

and it worked :)

also, if you have more params to pass you can like

```
import cProfile
cProfile.runctx('self.doSomething(x,y,z)',globals(),locals())
```

Thanks for all help

Comment: as a small note, you can also use `cProfile.run('self.doSomething()')` and it'll work too. But it seems that `cProfile.runctx()` is more general.

Answer (score 3):

You need to fix various imprecisions (missing `self`, saying you're using class methods when there's no `classmethod` in sight, failing to inherit from `object`, ...) then make `profile` happy by giving it a string as it wants -- and the name of the instance must be made globally visible so that `profile` can actually use that string.  For example:

```
import profile
import time

class Class(object):

  def doSomething(self):
      time.sleep(0.1)

  def callMethod(self):
      global _o
      _o = self
      profile.run('_o.doSomething()')

o = Class()
o.callMethod()
```

Comment: This didn't work for me but daydreamers answer did work.